# Is there a way to power up a Mac Mini remotely?

Tags: remote-control, mac-mini, startup

Is there ANY way to Power Up a Mac Mini remotely?
Just to be clear, I don´t mean wake up from sleep but boot up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how your Mac Mini is connected to the internet (wifi, ethernet, firewall, age of the machine, NAT, …) it *should* be possible to do it using [Wake On LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Wake_on_Internet).

You could, for example, use a GUI software like [WakeOnLan](http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan/index.html).

Comment: a lot of routers have this option.  I use dd-wrt firmware on an Asus rt-n16, you can log in to the router remotely and issue a Wake On LAN command.

Comment: Isn't this just to Wake from sleep? Not from OFF?

Comment: @ozke : No, it also works from off state.

Comment: I guess it should work with ethernet.
The problem is the Mac Mini can only be accessed via WiFi and there's no other computer to trigger the "wake up" packet.

I guess the only way of doing this is just leave it always sleeping and use the remote or something. I miss good old days when Mac keyboards had a power button for the machine. :(

Comment: I can't see a way to get Wake on Lan to *power on* a Mac mini or Macbook. It will *wake* from sleep, but not *power on*.

Comment: [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Mac_hardware_.28OS_X.29) states that "Modern Mac hardware supports WoL functionality when the computer is in a sleep state, but it is not possible to wake up a Mac computer from a powered-off state."

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it's also possible to use the Energy Saver preference pane to schedule the machine to startup at a set time.

Answer (score 2):

As you describe it, no.

You could, however, get another computer or network-controlled device with the ability to cut off/restore power to a device, and remotely operate that (I'll try to find such a controller and link it here in a minute).  Then just set your mac-mini to auto-boot after a power failure.

Edit: example- http://www.42u.com/dataprobe_iboot_remote_reboot.htm

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can set, in the energy settings a scheduled time for the remote computer to start. At least if others have powered down the computer you know it will power up everyday on its own i.e. 6:00AM
I am setting up a remote MAC in the Philippines and others may power down instead of log off so I know if for example I set it to start everyday at 9:00PM philippine time it will be acccessable to me in the US everyday at 6:00AM.

Another idea if your in the US is to use iDevice, a switch that you plug into the power outlet then plug the MAC into. These are great devices that use apple home kit and I use them to power cycle my remote cameras that freez once in awhile and the company who makes the camera said to power cycle to restore the cameras. These devices use their own internet access and work great unfortunately they only make the 110 vac version. Also you must have the MAC set up to restart on power failure.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another cool thing you can try is to download Remote to your iPhone and setup a library to iTunes. In my case my computer starts automatically when opening the application! =)

Comment: I would guess that this requires Wake On Lan to work as well.