# Wake on LAN for MBP late 2009

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, remote-control

Is it possible to wake my MBP via Magic Packets from power down? I read [Is there a way to power up a Mac Mini remotely?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/power-up-mac-mini-remotely), but that does not seem to work from power down. "Wake for network access" in "Energy Saver" prefpane is ticked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the only (recent) hardware that had [Lights out Management](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2773) (LOM) is the now discontinued Xserve. You will need separate hardware to control the power in response to WOL packets (or other signals) to start the current line up of macs from a powered down state.

Apple's [current implementation is focused on sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Sleep_Proxy_Service_%28Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy%29). The macs need to  - first boot up as they leave the network interfaces listening to wake from only from sleep. Powering down the mac turns off all power to the network interfaces.

Comment: Great job, apple...